Qt Widget ui tree access vs findchild
I am working on a Qt Widget c++ program where all the access to the ui elements are made using the findchild function.
For example:
tab->findChild<QPushButton *>("myPushButton")->setEnabled(true);

However I was used to access the ui elements through the ui tree like in the Getting Started Programming with Qt Widgets example from Qt.
Or for example in the following way:
ui->tab->myPushButton->setEnabled(true);

I would like to know what is the difference between these two accesses?
When is it recommanded to use the findchild function and when is it recommended to use the ui tree?

One approach involves walking a tree and comparing names, the other involves following a pointer. Obviously, only do the first when you are dynamically modifying the widget tree. And even then only if there is no better suited datastructure.

findChild/findChildren should be your last resort. I would go even further than @Botje and say that if you are dynamically modifying the widget tree but you can store the added widgets into a member variable of your parent class (e.g. there is a fixed number of them), you should do it this way. If you cannot do that but all you need is emit/receive signals in the added widgets, then just do the connection and forget about them (and delete will be automatic).

I have only ever encountered 1 case where I needed syntax like your first snippet and that was when I knew nothing about the parent widget; for instance, I have an application where I want all windows to have the same behavior in terms of enabling/disabling widgets (view vs edit mode). In that case, a centralized manager singleton can loop over widget->findChildren<XXX>() and do what it needs with them: XXX might be simple widgets like QCheckBox, QLineEdit (to enable/disable), ... or QAbstractItemView (on which the edit flags are changed).

Other than what explained above, there are also rare cases for which using findChild() may be necessary: when using complex widgets that are completely constructed by Qt classes or internal functions, and some access to their children is required. For instance, the widgets in a non-native QFileDialog (the views, the stacked widget containing them, the location combo box, etc.), or the individual elements in a QCalendarWidget such as its year/month buttons.
